# Regex matching changing path

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regexes in JavaScript, and going by the documentation, I tried to come up with a regex to match the following:

```
/folder1/33/folder2/34/file.txt
/folder1/somefolder1/somefolder2/folder2/ab7/file2.exr
/folder1/fol1/fol2/folder2/fol1/fol2/file3
```

In other words I start with `/folder1`, then anything, then `/folder2`, then anything.

What seemed logical to me was:

```
\/folder1\/.*\/folder2\/.*
```

But it does not match.

Comment: Works fine for me. *How* are you running it?

Comment: [You sure it doesn't match?](http://prntscr.com/9talzx)

Comment: [`/\/folder1\/.*\/folder2\/.*/g` does match the strings you showed](https://regex101.com/r/oJ8kZ5/1).

Comment: i am using webstorm regex matcher ( which shows up while coding)

Comment: http://regexr.com/ also tried it here... with no matcch

Comment: @MiddleMan [works fine for me](http://regexr.com/3cku1)

Comment: When you say "it does not match" please show exactly the code you used and the results obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
\/folder1\/.*?\/folder2\/.*
```

.* => till end of string

.*? => till upcoming character that is /folder2

Comment: This is irrelevant for the match result. And the explanation is wrong, `.*` does not necessarily match until the end of the string.